# Can you keep a piglin from turning into a zombified-piglin in the overworld?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it possible for you to keep a piglin unzombified in the overworld, whether it be through use of commands or otherwise?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Piglin#Zombification):

> When in the Overworld or the End, piglins transform into zombified piglins after 15 seconds.

This is part of their behavior, and cannot be protected from this any way in game (like putting them in water or protecting them from the sun, etc. After 15 seconds, they will turn into a Zombie Piglin.

However, through [Commands](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Piglin#Entity_data):

> **IsImmuneToZombification:** 1 or 0 (true/false) – If set to true, the piglin does not transform to a zombified piglin when in the Overworld.

By altering their NBT data, you can set this value to make them immune to this effect.

Comment: What an aptly named NBT! Thank you, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

For 1.19 you can do:

`/data modify entity EntityUUID IsImmmuneToZombification append value 1`

I've used it to make some piglin immune to the overworld zombification.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a command block reapeat always active with the command:
`/event entity @e[type=piglin] stop_zombification_event`

Comment: This appears to be a Bedrock Edition command for a Java Edition question.

Comment: From a suggested edit: "That works but in bedrock it will show in chat many times over and over as long as the piglin is alive"

Answer (score 0):

The command in the repeating, always active command block should actually be:

```
/event entity @e[type=piglin_brute] stop_zombification_event
```

(make sure its pigeon_brute or it won't work)

Comment: This question is for Java Edition

Answer (score 0):

As of update 1.16 and 1.17, it doesn't work.

I typed `/event entity @e [type=minecraft:piglin] stop_zombiefication_event` in to Bedrock edition, and it doesn't work. It just replies "stop_zombiefication_event couldn't be executed on piglin" and it zombies.

This also doesn't works with `/event entity @e [type=minecraft:piglin] stop_transformating`.

Comment: This appears to be a comment on another answer. You should downvote another answer or comment on it to explain why it is wrong. There is another answer that lists how to do this in 1.16

Answer (score -1):

Currently no such option is known. Maybe in the future someone finds a way, but as of now, the change is inevitable.

Answer (score -1):

Use this command:

```
/summon hoglin ~ ~ ~ {IsImmuneToZombification}
```

This works as of Minecraft 1.16